# 2D Pixel Shader removing alpha channel from color

Tags: c#, xna, shader, alpha, hlsl

So, I'm trying to make a game in XNA, and I'm applying a pixel shader to my level so I can add effects to the gameplay screen. The shader itself is working nicely, but it has one flaw that really pushes back performance. As long as the shader is active, anything I draw to the screen acts as though it was drawn with it's alpha channel at the maximum. I'm drawing a lot of things using XNA's built in `Color` class, and much of it has varying alpha. However, the shader seems to ignore all of this. This occurs even if I just return the source from the shader.

I've seen a few possible solutions. The first of these was to draw to a RenderTarget2D and, while this did solve this issue, it caused more serious problems with alpha that I don't even want to go into.

I have seen a few people claim that multiplying the colours by the alpha value in the shader seems to help, but that made absolutely no difference, which suggests to me that the alpha value input is always being read as 1.

Here are some images to illustrate my problem:

[image: This is the result with the shader active][image: This is what it's supposed to look like]

Hopefully, someone knows how to resolve this.

Comment: I've done a bit more testing. It seems any alteration to the colour in XNA's SpriteBatch.Draw method is removed, making all textures be drawn using "Color.White". This is very problematic for me.

Comment: Yes, if your pixel shader is ignoring the alpha value, or not passing it through, then you’ll see that effect when using that shader. Post your shader code.

Comment: After discovering that it ignored all tint effects, and not just alpha, I searched slightly differently, and found my solution. I'll leave this here in case anyone has the same issue. The solution I found was here:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/35420.aspx

It uses the SpriteBatch colour argument and simply multiplies the input by it, giving you the tint you want.

Thanks for trying to help. For the record, my shader had practically no code in it. It took a colour argument and returned it.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I've explicitly tried returning a color with an Alpha of 0, but it still put the pixels on the screen. -- What the heck?

Answer (score 0):

In your Draw() method, you need to call:
`GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.NonPremultiplied;` before calling any methods that invoke your shader (i.e. `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives`, etc.).

Otherwise, the framework assumes the alpha value has been premultiplied and that it can just blit the RGB values right to the framebuffer.